# addEventListener is null with PHP but works with HTML

Tags: javascript

Both files are in the same directory. I don't know why the `EventListener` for `addForm` is `null` because I wrote the exact same code in `HTML` and it is working.
Any ideas? Thank you!

[project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrNzQ.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3uCK.png)

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxOUb.png)

[form-details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDwDq.png)

[sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqA0k.png)

[new-listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpuvA.png)

**add-jobs.js**

```
window.onload=function(){
    const addForm = document.querySelector(".add");

    addForm.addEventListener("submit", e =>{

        e.preventDefault();
        const todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
        console.log(todo);
    });

};``
```

**add-jobs.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add A Job</h1>
    <form id="new-listing" action="add-database.php" method="POST">
        <p>
        <label for="position">Position : </label>
        <input name="position" type="text" placeholder="e.g Assistant CEO" required>  
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="job-type">Type : </label>
        <select name="job-type">
            <option value="fulltime">Full-time</option>
            <option value="parttime">Part-time</option>
            <option value="temporary">Temporary</option>

        </select>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="location">Location : </label>
        <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="e.g Bangkok" required>  
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="salary">Salary (per year) : </label>
        <input name="salary" type="number">
        <select name="currency">
            <option value="usd">USD</option>
            <option value="mmk" selected data-default>MMK</option>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="requirements">Requirements : </label>
        <select name="job-type">
            <option value="fulltime">Full-time</option>
            <option value="parttime">Part-time</option>
            <option value="temporary">Temporary</option>

        </select>
        </p>
            <form class="add">
                <label for="keywords">Keywords : </label>     
                <input type="text" name="add" value=""/>                      
            </form>
            <ul class="list-keywords">
            </ul>
        <p>

        <label for="description">Description : </label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
        </p>

        <?php 
    $tm = time();
    $publisheddate = date("m/d/y",$tm);

    echo "Date of publication : ". $publisheddate."<br>";
?>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
<script src="./add-jobs.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Page Source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add A Job</h1>
    <form id="new-listing" action="add-database.php" method="POST">
        <p>
        <label for="position">Position : </label>
        <input name="position" type="text" placeholder="e.g Assistant CEO" required>  
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="job-type">Type : </label>
        <select name="job-type">
            <option value="fulltime">Full-time</option>
            <option value="parttime">Part-time</option>
            <option value="temporary">Temporary</option>

        </select>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="location">Location : </label>
        <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="e.g Bangkok" required>  
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="salary">Salary (per year) : </label>
        <input name="salary" type="number">
        <select name="currency">
            <option value="usd">USD</option>
            <option value="mmk" selected data-default>MMK</option>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="requirements">Requirements : </label>
        <select name="job-type">
            <option value="fulltime">Full-time</option>
            <option value="parttime">Part-time</option>
            <option value="temporary">Temporary</option>

        </select>
        </p>
            <div id="add">
                <label for="keywords">Keywords : </label>     
                <input type="text" name="add" value=""/>                      
            </div>
            <ul class="list-keywords">
            </ul>
        <p>

        <label for="description">Description : </label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
        </p>

        Date of publication : 08/17/19<br>    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
<script src="./add-jobs.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at add-jobs.js:16

Comment: Try adding the code within window load event

Comment: Hi, I tried both (the window load event and the ./) and still not working :(

Comment: Ah, so the script is loading OK but it can't see the existing DOM? Not sure if an onload will help since the script tags are at the bottom. Are you serving this with WAMP or something like that? Can you access any other elements on the page?

Comment: I am using XAMPP. I added the pictures of all the files in my post

Comment: Can you show the code where you added window load event ?

Comment: Also best way to debug is using console. Try executing `document.querySelector(".add")` in console and share us screenshot of what you get so we can know better

Comment: I added the code with  window load event, thank you.

Comment: I just added the screenshot as "console"

Comment: Are you sure that the same code is what you are using? Because if so then console should output dom element of .add class

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll("form")` in console and see what dom elements are selected, share the screen shot

Comment: Yes same code, I just remove some <p> because it was a bit long otherwise but I just edited again and now showed the full code

Comment: Thank you so muc, I do have something, a nodelist of lenght 1 (picture in my post called form)

Comment: form-details to see more

Comment: I think I know my error. I have a form inside a form

Comment: One last thing, can you share screenshot of view source of that page from browser?

Comment: I meant view page source from right click menu of your browser. In your case it should be `view-source:http://localhost:8080/hrasia/add-jobs.php`

Comment: Done, uder "page source" section, thanks

Comment: Okay, now i see what you need. Try this `addForm = document.querySelector("#new-listing");` and check

Comment: Done, I also changed the "add form" with a "add div". The title of the image is new-listing

Comment: I mean in your js replace `const addForm` line with `const addForm = document.querySelector("#new-listing");` and it should work fine

Comment: yes it is working. However, I can't have a form within a form? What can be the alternative?

Comment: You don't need to, it has no purpose as i see your in your case. If you really need a button just for single row just add a button add click event to it and access the add input on click instead of form submission

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198104/discussion-on-question-by-jean-vreux-addeventlistener-is-null-with-php-but-works).

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
addForm.addEventListener("submit", e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
    console.log(todo);
});
```

by

```
addForm[0].addEventListener("submit", e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const todo = addForm[0].add.value.trim();
    console.log(todo);
});
```

or simply give an id to your form ex id="frm" and use

const addForm = document.querySelector("#frm");

Comment: I tried the [0] but still the same error. I will try the ID

Comment: why do you use nested forms ?

Comment: 4.10.3 The form element

Content model:

Flow content, but with no form element descendants.